# Calculate minimum value of Bitvector in Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I have the following piece of code:
    (declare-const L4 (_ BitVec 6))
    (declare-const L1 (_ BitVec 6))
    (declare-const L0 (_ BitVec 6))
    (declare-const l2 (_ BitVec 6))

```
(assert (= l2 (_ bv8 6)))

;; All is encoding the set that contains {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
(define-const All (_ BitVec 6) #b111111) 
;; Empty is encoding the empty set
(define-const Empty (_ BitVec 6) #b000000) 

(define-fun LT_l ((S (_ BitVec 6)) (l (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    ;; True if for all x in S x < l
    (= (bvand (bvshl All l) S) Empty))

(define-fun is_in ((e (_ BitVec 6)) (S (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
   ;; True if e is an element of the "set" S.
   (not (= (bvand (bvshl (_ bv1 6) e) S) Empty))) 

(define-fun is_minimal ((e (_ BitVec 6)) (S (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    ;; True if e is the minimal element of S
    (and (is_in e S) ;; S contains e
         ;; (1 << e) - 1 represents the set of elements that are smaller than e
         (= (bvand (bvsub (bvshl (_ bv1 6) e) (_ bv1 6)) S) Empty))) 

;; To encode that forall x in L0 and forall y in L1. x < y
(define-fun LT ((L0 (_ BitVec 6)) (L1 (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    ; True if forall x in L0 and forall y in L1, x < y
    (or (= L0 Empty)
        (= L1 Empty)
        (exists ((min (_ BitVec 6))) (and (is_minimal min L1) (LT_l L0 min)))))

(assert (not (= L0 Empty)))
(assert (not (= L1 Empty)))
(assert (not (= L4 Empty)))
(assert (LT_l L4 l2))
(assert (LT L0 L1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
(assert (LT L1 L0))
(check-sat)
```

When I run this code I get the model is:
    sat
    (model 
      (define-fun min!0 () (_ BitVec 6)
        #b000011)
      (define-fun L1 () (_ BitVec 6)
        #b001000)
      (define-fun L0 () (_ BitVec 6)
        #b000100)
      (define-fun L4 () (_ BitVec 6)
        #b000100)
      (define-fun l2 () (_ BitVec 6)
        #b001000)
    )
    unsat

Why is the result of `min` is:

```
(define-fun min!0 () (_ BitVec 6)
    #b000011)
```

and not b001000 since the smallest value of L1 is this and not b000011.

Someone can explain me?

Finally, I define the function Lt_l that checks if for all x in S x < l, but now I wanted to do GT_l that checks if for all x in S l < x. I have the following code:

```
(define-fun GT_l ((S (_ BitVec 6)) (l (_ BitVec 6))) Bool
    (= (bvand (bvneg (bvshl (_ bv0 6) l)) S) Empty))
```

But this does not work why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are representing sets using bit-vectors. For example, the bit-vector `#b101000` represents the set `{5, 3}`. The output `(define-fun L1 () (_ BitVec 6) #b001000)` is essentially saying that `L1` is the "set" `{3}`. One possible confusion is that bit-vectors are being used to represent sets and elements. The bit-vector `min!0` represents an element. The output `(define-fun min!0 () (_ BitVec 6) #b000011)` is saying that `min!0` is the value `3`, and it is indeed the "minimal value" in `L1`.

Comment: Why when I do `(simplify (LT_l (_ bv3 6) (_ bv2 6)))` the result is true and isn't false? For 3 is greater than 2 and is not less. Why this happens?

Comment: In `(LT_l S l)`, the first element encodes a "set". `(_ bv3 6)` is `000011` in binary, and is encoding the set `{0, 1}`. Every element of this "set" is smaller than `2`. This is why the result is true.